# Can I create a virtual directory that points to a letter drive that doesn't have wwwroot directory?

Tags: iis, virtual-directory

Greetings all and please forgive me if my question is too cheap.

I have drives on our server, C:\ drive and D:\ drive.

IIS is installed and configured.

C:\drive has inetpub\wwroot

D:\drive has only inetpub; no wwwroot.

I am trying to create a virtual directory and have it point to the D:\ drive that doesn't have wwwroot directory.

Will this still work or do I have need to move my physical files to C:\drive since it has wwwroot directory?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just an Microsoft preference to put them in wwwroot

You can point a virtual directory anywhere you wish.

C:\Temp if you feel the need!